# how to insert value from one table to other table in sqlite3 database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am new in iphone i am  developing a application with data base i am create a database and have to table we want to insert one table value to other. I am not understand how do this.

if any body know help me with coding.

Comment: 21 questions with no accepted answers... you should accept answers to your questions if they solve your problem - that will encourage others to continue helping you

Answer (score 0):

Nested query: `INSERT INTO Table VALUES (SELECT blah...)`